# What is reason of placement of format() inside LocalDate or LocalTime, even if there is no possible way of using it

Tags: java, java-time

The classes LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime are final, objects can't be created out of it, so static reference cannot be made to the non static method format().
Also all three classes mentioned inherits from Object class only. So there is no superclass of these three classes from which this method can be accessed.
Neither this method comes from any of interface implemented by LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime classes nor we can override this method as all three classes are final.
Please explain me essence of format() in any of above mentioned classes.

Comment: You should be using Java classes, not extending them.  The `format` method formats the date and time objects into a displayable `String`.

Comment: _"... are final, objects can't be created out of it"_ - Incorrect. Those classes _can_ be instantiated.  What you can't do is _extend_ them, i.e. `MyClass extends LocalDate...`  You seem to be confusing `final` with `abstract`.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. You have *"... are final, objects can't be created out of it,..."* . That appears to be false. If I have `public final class Foo { ...`, I *can* still instantiate `Foo` type Objects.

Comment: "*can't be created out of it*" there are a couple of factory methods to do that, simple example `LocalDate.now()` or `LocalDate.of(2023, MAY, 12)`; and using that method: `LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)`

Comment: A class which has instance methods yet can never be instantiated would indeed be quite odd. Luckily, this is not the case here. A `final` class simply cannot be _extended_; that has nothing to do with the ability to _instantiate_ a class. Now, the classes you mentioned do not have visible constructors, so you will not be able to directly instantiate them with the `new` keyword. But they all define "static factory methods" which can, as expected, be called without an instance. You can then call instance methods on the objects returned by the static factory methods.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... The classes LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime are final, objects can't be created out of it ..."*

Your terminology is incorrect.

In *Java*, an *[object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science))* is a *[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)*, typically an *[instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)*.

And, when a *class* is defined with the *[final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)* keyword, it cannot be *[encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))*.
An *object* can be created, though.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2023, 11, 9);
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of(12, 34);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 11, 9, 12, 34);
```

> *"... so static reference cannot be made to the non static method format().  ..."*

Unlike the *[of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int))* method, the *[format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter))* method is not defined as *[static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)*, so you'll need to use an *instance* to access it.

```java
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of(12, 34);
lt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
```